# If the sides of triangle are decided by throwing a die thrice the probability that the triangle is a equilateral triangle or isosceles triangle is

Tags: probability

My idea is:

No.of ways of getting a triangle which is equilateral or isosceles is:

First I fix same side lengths for two sides as for both isosceles and equilateral two sides should be same

1 1 (1 chance "1" )

2 2 (2 chances"1,2")

3 3 ("1,2,3,4")

4 4 ("1,2,3,4,5")

5 5 (all six possible)

6 6 (all six possible)

There is only 1 chance for the first one as by triangle rule sum of squares of two sides must be greater than other side

So no. Of possible cases is  $1+2+4+5+6+6 = 24$

Total no.of cases is $= 216$

As there are three dice and each side have $6$ chances so $216$

Now probability $= 24/216 = 1/9$

Comment: If you throw a six-sided die thrice, there are $6^3 = 216$ possible outcomes.  Also, the requirement for a triangle is that the sum of the lengths of any two sides must exceed the length of the third side.

Comment: Thanks for replying to it I made a mistake in writing 256 in place of 216 and I can't change it later

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  You can make changes by clicking on the Edit button at the bottom of your post.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

There are the following possibilities to construct the triangles:
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
a& b& c & \#\\
x&x&x& 6\\
2&2&1,3 & 2\times 3=6\\
3&3& 1,2,4,5 & 4\times 3=12\\
4&4&  1,2,3,5,6 & 5\times 3=15\\
5&5&  1,2,3,4,6 & 5\times 3=15\\
6&6&  1,2,3,4,5 & 5\times 3=15\\
\end{array}
$$
That means that the probability in question is
$$
\frac{69}{216}=\frac{23}{72}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

According to N.F. Taussig's comment: *...the requirement for a triangle is that the sum of the lengths of any two sides must exceed the length of the third side*. So it's not about the squares.

Also, by using the law of cosines you can realize that, for example, a triangle with two sides of $4$ and $4$ can have a side of $6$ as well.

So, the total number of possible cases is $27$.

Comment: While some of your cases can only occur in one way, others can occur in three ways, depending on the way the numbers are distributed on the three dice.

Comment: Oh you are right. I also read user's answer and that's pretty correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is the case of conditional probability. We shouldn't take 216 in the denominator.
For example 1,1,6 should not be counted either in numerator or denominator.

Numerator contains the cases of isosceles and equilateral which will be 69.
Denominator contains the case of number of triangles which will be 111.

So, probability will be 69/111 or 23/37

Answer (score 0):

The first throw of the dies is a number from 1 to 6.
The probability the second throw is that same number is 1/6. The probability the second throw is not that number is 5/6. The probability the third throw is the same as the first is also 1/6 so the probability the triangle is 1/6*1/6= 1/36.

If the first two throws are the same, the probability is 5/6 thirds is not so the probability of this, giving an isosceles triangle, is 1/6*5/6= 5/36.
If the first two throws are not the same, the probability the third throw is the same as the first is 1/6 and the probability is the same as the second is 1/6.  The probability of either of these cases is 5/6*1/6= 5/36.
So the probability the triangle isosceles is 5/36+ 5/36+ 5/36= 15/36.

(And the probability the triangle is scalene (neither equilateral nor isosceles) is 1- 1/36- 5/36= 30/36= 5/6.)